# Clarification needed on Spring MVC without using Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand Spring MVC in more detail what I currently know. I am referring to online tutorials and books. As I understand, Spring MVC framework has "Front controller" and "MVC" design patterns.

The front controller (DispatcherServlet) uses the `HandlerMapping` for mapping URL to the controller classes. **I am not using annotations because I want to understand what the framework does behind the scenes**.

In this quest, I created a simple web-application based on Spring MVC, the code is below:

## Controller code:

```
public class SimpleSpringController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("welcome","welcomeMessage", "welcome user!");
        return mw;
    }
}
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app>
        <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

## Spring xml configuration

```
<beans>

    <bean id="HandlerMapping1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean name="/welcome" class="com.example.controller.SimpleSpringController"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value> </property>
        <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value> </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The application works as expected.

The concepts which I am not able to understand is on the spring configuration xml where we specify the `HandlerMapping` and `ViewResolver` implementations.

For example, we have the following bean definition in the above spring xml configuration:

```
<bean id="HandlerMapping1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
```

In above xml config,  `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is one of the implementations of the `HandlerMapping` interface.

The  bean id for this is `HandlerMapping1`, which is just a random identifier ( I could have very well chosen `MyHandlerMapping`). The following are the doubts:

1. Who reads this configuration file? Do front controller read this configuration file?
2. How does the framework knows that the id of `HandlerMapping` implementation in above case is  `HandlerMapping1`. Usually we do getBean("beanId"), where we specifically know what a particular bean id is. How come spring framework is automatically infer that this is the implementation class of `HandlerMapping`.

Any inputs to understand this would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Initialization

In Spring the front controller is the [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html), this extends the [`FrameworkServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html). The `FrameworkServlet` by default creates a `XmlWebApplicationContext` and tries to read an XML file named `<servlet-name>-servlet.xml` (this is when using a `web.xml`!). (All this can be overridden by setting the appropriate `init-param`s for the configured `DispatcherServlet`).

The `DispatcherServlet` will after loading eventually call the [`initStrategies`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L483) method. This method will configure the delegation strategies for the `DispatcherServlet`. It will first try and detect most of the strategies by type (like `HandlerMaping`, `HandlerAdapter`, `ViewResolver` etc) and some by name (`localeResolver`, `themeResolver`, `messageSource` etc.). If that cannot be found the default strategies for a given interface will be installed. Those defaults are defined in the [`DispatcherServlet.properties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.properties) inside Spring.

**Important:** As soon as you define a strategy yourself the defaults for that strategy don't apply anymore!. For instance if you have a `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` in your configuration, the default configuration for `HandlerMapping` isn't loaded anymore as you provided explicit configuration.

## Request Handling

After startup the `DispatcherServlet` is ready to handle request.

[image: DispatcherServlet Flow] 
*Image comes from the [Spring Framework reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc)*

### Handler Selection and execution

What happens is when a request is handled by the `DispatcherServlet` it will check all configured [`HandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html)s to see if one is able to provide a handler (a `Controller` or `@Controller` is just one of the handler types that can be handled) for the given request. As soon as a handler is found, it will lookup a [`HandlerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerAdapter.html) for the detect handler. If that is also found the found handler together with the current `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are passed to the `HandlerAdapter`s `handle` method.

### View resolution

Now if a [`ModelAndView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) is being returned from the `HandlerAdapter.handle` method a `View` is going to be resolved if the `ModelAndView.getViewName()` method returns a name, this is going to be passed on the an to a [`ViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) to be resolved into a [`View`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html).

When a `View` is either being resolver or being returned from the `ModeAndView.getView()` method, the `render` method is going to be called to let the chosen `View` render itself. With the (optional) model from the `ModelAndView` class.

### Exception Handling

When an exception occurs during processing of the request this exception is first being passed to the configured [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html)s. If one of them can handle it the selected `HandlerExceptionResolver`s `resolveException` method is being invoked. This method, just like the `HandlerAdapter.handle` method can return a `ModelAndView`, when this happens this is processed in the same way as a normal request (see *View Resolution*).

**Note:** This is also to some degree documented in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) of the `DispatcherServlet`. You can find all the default strategies and well known names in there, as well as a explanation of the request handling flow.

Comment: Thanks so much for the wonderful explanation, I need to read it with full focus :). BTW, the way you have described the flow is awesome, I am curious to know how to build this kind of understanding (and so the confidence!). The books which I refer on Spring doesn't cover at the inner workings of the Spring and my mind always is thirsty on how this is working internally.  The reference Documentation I feel slightly complicated (as of now), can you suggest me how to have better understanding, and not just "how to do a given task using the framework"? Thanks again!

Comment: Well that is 14 years of working with Spring, contributing to Spring and writing books about Spring. Also being a former Interface21/SpringSource consultant also helps :). But I like to know how things work, it is Open Source so look at the source code and read a couple of good books on the topic.

Comment: Impressive! BTW could you suggest some books both at beginner level and some at advanced level, including your book :).

Answer (score 2):

1. The controller does not read the xml file, Spring does.
2. Your spring xml configuration is loaded in by Spring which wires everything together. Autowiring is taking place which is wiring by the Type, of which HandlerMapping1 can provide for the interface HandlerMapping.

   Interestingly BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping is the default handler mapping class, so it is the one created by the DispatcherServlet when Spring cannot find any handler mapping class declared.

   If you want to try and see something break, create a duplicate bean named HandlerMapping2 and read the error logging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so it means that Autowire by type is taking place. But in configuration file there is no mention of Autowire? Also, I tried duplicate bean as you suggested, however the application still works. I am more confused in this now!

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring framework reads the xml.
2. Well, for spring MVC to work, the handler should be instantiated.
   The spring MVC framework needs to resolve the mappings and so we
   have handlers like BeanNameUrl..., ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping,
   etc

   However, HandlerMapping is not generally used by your application
   code. So you need not specify whether this bean is autowired by type
   or not. It is used by the framework. So it is autowired in the
   **framework** classes by type.

   You can try defining the bean in the xml without any id, name
   something like

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
   ```

   and it should still work.

   Id or name is required only when you want to refer to the bean by id
   or name for your use. Framework classes which need this handler
   mapping don't refer to the bean of HandlerMapping type by id or
   name. Framework will 'scan' the xml (or the loaded classes) and if
   it finds a concrete class in there of type
   (org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping) then it won't
   complain.

   To think of a similar case for example, when you run the junit
   tests, the engine will scan for all the methods annotated with @Test
   and it will 'know' that these are the methods it needs to execute as
   tests. It does not matter what the names of test methods are.

Hope this answers the query.